# Wrong question and answer count at Accounts tab on SE

Tags: bug, profile-page, user-accounts

In the past, I have reported an [issue with the answer count at the accounts tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122218/wrong-answer-count-at-accounts-tab). Later, I deleted the post, assuming that the bug had been fixed.

I have just noticed that the counts at [my StackExchange Accounts tab](https://stackexchange.com/users/902274/rob-w?tab=accounts) and [the summary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938089/rob-w?tab=summary) differ:

[image: Accounts tab (1 should be 2, 1795 should be 1802)].

Is this intentional (if yes, when are the values updated?) or a bug?

Comment: `[status-caching]`? Maybe not-- your 1796th answer was pretty far back. (few days)