# Stack Exchange account not shows correct stats

Tags: bug, stack-exchange, user-accounts

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/users/756941/nazik) is my Stack Overflow profile. I have 48 answers.

> [image]

[This](https://stackexchange.com/users/394477/nazik?tab=accounts) is my Stack Exchange Profile. There it shows only 47 answers on Stack Overflow.

> [image]

Surely it's not caching issue, my last answer is posted on a week ago.

Why it shows like this?

Comment: Could just be a data replication delay. That's my best guess.

Comment: May be a caching issue.

Comment: @Raynold, caching for 8 days?

Comment: @Raynold, I don't think it can be caching issue, because when i viewed my SE Profile, it shows accurate data. Updated till yesterday's activity.

Comment: @Azik, When i saw your S.O. profile, i got it's reason, but let any moderator answer it. Perhaps i am not allowed to answer this question.

Comment: @Lucifer - Why moderators? anyone who know/find the reason can answer. And by saying moderators you mean devs? :)

Comment: @hims056, **any moderators**

Comment: You might have some deleted answers maybe? PS, it's happening in my case too. Between [here](http://stackexchange.com/users/1224532/hjpotter92?tab=accounts) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1190388/hjpotter92)

Comment: I believe that after you'll post new answer on SO the issue will get "resolved".

Comment: Possibly related: [Wrong question and answer count at Accounts tab on SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132357/wrong-question-and-answer-count-at-accounts-tab-on-se)